# Sublime text error when uploading (gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed)

Tags: php, sublimetext2, codeigniter-2

Im use ftpsync in sublime text 2, this is working good before and suddenly got this error.. Im googling and still got no working solution.. This is the console:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\FTPSync.py", line 957, in makeConnection
  File ".\ftpsyncwrapper.py", line 318, in connect
  File ".\ftpsyncwrapper.py", line 290, in retryingCommand
  File ".\ftpsyncwrapper.py", line 284, in call
  File ".\lib2\ftplib.py", line 140, in connect
  File ".\socket.py", line 500, in create_connection
gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed
```

Comment: looks like dns lookup fails (getaddrinfo). Try setting ip/host explicitly in your /etc/hosts (nix based), or system32/drivers/etc/hosts.

Comment: i guess no, cz i still can upload and download via filezilla :(